# How to upload files into azure media services directly from client(azure website)?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

How to upload files into azure media services directly from client browser using (azure hosted website) ?and also to azure blob storage using azure website, without using any intermediate server.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far and what issues you are facing. As a side note, you may find these two blog posts useful for uploading files from a local computer directly into blob storage: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ and http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/.

Comment: we have hosted website in azure. I need to upload media file into azure media services, documents to azure storage container using my azure website. I have done this through intermediate server(content moved to intermediate server, from there moved to azure using WCF service). Now I want this to done through azure website (browser upload direct to azure). Moreover is there anyway to host windows service, web service in azure (like azure website) without using VM(web role, worker role).

Comment: can anyone suggest regarding above questions..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, Azure Media Services does offer a REST API. In your web application, you can do all the things required to create media assets, set encoding jobs, and the like once you've had the media file uploaded.

After looking, Guarav's post seems spot on: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

Comment: Hi detrimentalg, In my website I have added azure media service SDK, and uploaded video content to media services through local host site.encoding and encryption also working fine.  After publishing to azure the video file is not uploading to media server. the content size is (not available). encryption also not happening. is this file path problem ? and moreover while uploading , the browser's progress is running till publish URL generation. It takes more time for large video files upload, encryption.

Comment: @venkiv as you describe it, it seems the same what happened with me, check this git issue I opened, here is the link:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-tutorials/issues/8